# Retrieve JSON string from URL in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm trying to get a Json string from an Url in a windows phone 8 application (the page requires an authentication and I think that's where my code is failing), I'm using the following code:

```
    public WebClient client = new WebClient();
    public string result;

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        string username = "username";
        string password = "password";
        string url = "myurl";
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
    void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        result = e.Result;
    }
```

However, when run the app, I got a **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException** at **e.result**

Going into **InnerException** I see this:

> [System.Net.WebException] {System.Net.WebException: An exception
>   occurred during a WebClient request.  --->
>   System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: A request with this method
>   cannot have a request body.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}   System.Net.WebException

I've tried with HttpClient but I got the same problem. I would like to know if somebody knows how to solve this.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I've tried navigating to the page on my phone using IE, and then the IE Mobile says: "Unsupported Address, IE Mobile doesn't support this type of address and can't display this page". That's why the app is crashing too?

Comment: when you try with another address whats happening ?

Comment: I got the same error (the pages URLs are something like: "http://180.200.1.231:4567/..."). Now I tried adding  `client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip"` , and then I got a "Server Not Found exception"

Comment: try with add http://    180. ....

Comment: I'm doing that, the URL that I'm parsing have the "http://", but I can't even get the Json string. I don't know if I'm making some code mistakes or if there's something that I'm missing on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GET Method (with/without Credentials)**

```
private string username = "user";
private string password = "passkey";
private string myUrl = "http://some_url.com/id?=20";
private WebClient client = new WebClient();

private void retrieveJson()
{
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(myUrl), UriKind.Relative);
}
//WebClient String (json content) Download
private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        // You will get you Json Data here..
        var myJSONData = e.Result;
        JObject JsonData = JObject.Parse(myJSONData);
        //Do something with json 
        //Ex: JsonData["Array1"][5]
}
```

**POST Method (with/without Credentials)**

```
private string username = "user";
private string password = "passkey";
private string myUrl = "http://some_url.com/id?=20";
private WebClient client = new WebClient();
private string parameters = "{\"I_NAME\":\"0000"\"}"; //Example

private void postMethod()
{
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        client.Headers["Content-Length"] = parameters.Length.ToString();
        client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);

        client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(myUrl), "POST", parameters);
}

private void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            var myJSONData = e.Result;
            JObject JsonData = JObject.Parse(myJSONData);
        }
}
```